# Checking for superadmin role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, cancan, rolify

I have set up a base application with ActiveAdmin, Cancan, Devise and Rolify. It is using a single user model (no separate admin/user).

Works like a charm so far, but I am struggling to limit access to the admin interface to users with the role 'superadmin' (roles are defined in a table 'roles' and assigned via users_roles)

In the activeadmin initalizer I have set:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_superadmin_user!
config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
config.cancan_ability_class = "AdminAbility"
```

Then I have created a file called admin_ability.rb:

```
class AdminAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.has_role?('superadmin')
      can :manage, :all
    end
 end
end
```

and this is my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def authenticate_superadmin_user!
    raise SecurityError unless current_user.try(:role => 'superadmin')
  end

  def access_denied(exception)
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end 
end
```

I think I am making a stupid mistake somewhere (and I have done a bit too much copy & paste) - probably in the application controller? Can somebody help me and explain what I have done wrong?

Much obliged!

Comment: any ideas how to get super admin working with devise: is there a link to such a page?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the `try` method incorrectly, change this:

```
def authenticate_superadmin_user!
  raise SecurityError unless current_user.try(:role => 'superadmin')
end
```

to this:

```
def authenticate_superadmin_user!
  raise SecurityError unless current_user.try(:role, 'superadmin')
end
```

The `try` method's first argument is the method name, then each argument after that will be arguments to that method. You're supplying a Hash to the try method which is invalid.

This is, of course, if your User model responds to `role` and accepts an argument of the role name. I would think you actually want to do: `current_user.try(:has_role?, 'superadmin')`

Comment: Ok, that's a bit embarrassing. Thanks! However, it still doesn't work - would :role access the role when it is in a different table? (roles are defined in a table 'roles' and assigned via users_roles)

Comment: I think I am trying way too much at once for a beginner - I'll be going back to my books to understand all this better :/ Right now I am struggling with too many of the basics. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Don't be embarrassed. We all have to start somewhere. The important thing is to keep trying until you get it. Happy coding :)